# Volatility Smile Approximation

Tags: options, implied-volatility

Does anyone know what type of model is used to model the skew and IVs inside Thinkorswim platform for its volatility smile approximation? I am trying to replicate but do not know where to start.

Any suggestion as to where to find more information would help too thanks.

Comment: An example would help. But probably SVI.

Comment: I'd you can give us an example of a smile (preferably a horrible one, as this is where the models tend to differ) then we miggt be able to tell you what parameterization they're using (if it's a standard one).

Comment: I assume you can at least contact them and find out. But if they are not willing to share their model name (which is not very likely), then you can probably guess by looking at a couple of features: near expiration fit, vol skew term structure, etc. SVI is not a model by the way. It's a parametrization and not arbitrage-free. SSVI sounds a bit more sophisticated for a large bank

Comment: Also what type of security are you looking at? There's a difference between trade-driven and quote-driven. I assume the IV comes from traded price of options.

Comment: @WillGu Why do you say SSVI is a bit more sophisticated for a large bacnk?

Comment: @will Aha. Based on my limited knowledge, I felt that SSVI calibration is more complicated than SVI. Since SVI has been widely used, I felt that SSVI is more likely to be an approach that a large bank would adopt. Apologies if my words sounded like the opposite.

Comment: @WillGu if they already have one model setup up in the calibration, then they've already jumped the larger hurdle. Also, raw svi is actually not that good for calibration, the model does not behave that well (especially if you have no minimum in the smile), there are other svi models which are much easier to calibrate.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what they use in Thinkorswim but I would assume some variation of a Cubic Spline, taking points along the skew and interpolating between them.

Comment: Why do you pressume a cubic spline?

Comment: Just because it is used in many places for volatility skews in other markets. True there is nothing to say it has to be a cubic spline. I just meant to say that it is one way of going about it.

Comment: I guess it depends how many points you have. If you have a lot it doesn't matter how you interpolate. If you have few few you need a model to fit and interpolate with.

Comment: I only hear about using Cubic Spline in FX option implied vols, since they are mostly trading 10 and 25 vol options. For equity options, how could you used cubic spline if there's no data for deep in/out-of-the-money option prices?